# Is there a way to define a protocol property for a struct dependent on which platform it is being used on?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I am working with iOS and WatchOS.

I have some structs that are being created on the iPhone and sent to the Apple Watch. The struct's target membership belongs to both the iOS app and the WatchKit Extension.

I want to define a protocol property for these structs that will only be accessible in the WatchKit Extension:

```
var complicationTimelineEntry: CLKComplicationTimelineEntry? { get }
```

`CLKComplicationTimelineEntry` is part of the `ClockKit` framework, which is not available on iOS, and so I am unable to compile.

Is there a way do this? Or should I abandon the one-size-fits-all method and break the problem down?

Currently, I am just creating an extension for the struct on the WatchOS side with another protocol. It works, but it is a few more steps than I would like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this:

```
protocol xyz {
  #if os(watchOS)
      var complicationTimelineEntry: CLKComplicationTimelineEntry? { get }
  #endif
  .
  .
  .
}
```

if basically checks what *os* the app is running on.

other available options `os(iOS)`, `os(tvOS)` and `os(OSX)`

Comment: Wow. Didn't know you could do that to import frameworks. Thanks!

Comment: @bkwebhero Happy to help !